# How to keep user logged in on my android application?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am building an android application similar to twitter and an API to communicate between both application and the server. I have developed the API and as of now the flow to login a user is, firstly the user send his or her username and password, once the system  receives the request, system checks both password and the username and if both username and password matches, system sends an access token to the user. This token will be attached to every other request that the user sends to the systems. For examples posting messages, retrieving messages and viewing profiles.
But the existing flow to request messages and profiles only works for a limited time as the access token expires after some time and the server no longer will accept the token.

*My question is:*

1. How do I keep a user always logged in like Facebook and other Social
   networking Android Application ?
2. How do I maintain the access tokens in the client side (Android
   Application) ?

It will be really great if anyone could explain me how I should attend to fix my problem.

**Note that: *I am using OAuth 2.0 for Laravel by lucadegasperi.***

Comment: you get the access tokens and login details to stored in Shared Preferences.

Comment: As of now I do store it in shared preferences. But what should I do when the stored token expires.

Comment: Check token value null or not before login if it's null go to login else skip the login screen